# When can I and when can I not use complex replacement?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

If I want to calculate: $$(2 cos(t))^3$$ Can I not replace cos(t) with $Re(e^{it})$ and calculate $(2e^{it})^3$ to be $8e^{3it}$ and thus the real part of this becomes 8cos(3t)?

But that answer is wrong. How do I know when I cannot use the method?

Comment: $(\mathfrak{R}(z))^3$ is in general different from $\mathfrak{R}(z^3)$.

Comment: The trouble is that $\text{Re}(z^3)\neq (\text{Re }z)^3$ in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(Re(e^{it}))^3$ is NOT equal to $Re((e^{it})^3)$

Comment: I see...so $\int Re(z)$ is equal to $Re(\int z)$? Because my class had an example of using complex replacement to solve something like $\int e^x cos(2x)$

Comment: @AlanCasallas: Sometimes the trick you mentioned is useful. Integration is linear, and so is $Re(z)$- so it works.

Answer (score 1):

If the system is linear in $b_k\cos(a_k t), a_k,b_k\in\mathbb{R}$, then you can use the complex replacement.

$$\sum_{k} b_k \cos(a_k t) \implies \sum_{k} b_k Re(\exp(i a_k t)) \implies Re(\sum_{k} b_k \exp(i a_k t) )$$

If it is not linear in $b_k\cos(a_k t)$, then you usually can not use the complex replacement.

For example
$$(2\cos t)^3=(e^{i t}+e^{-i t})^3=(e^{3i t}+e^{-3i t}+3e^{i t}+3e^{-i t})=2Re(e^{3i t})+6Re(e^{i t})$$